# Design pattern for one controller and many services

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, solid-principles

I'm currently facing problem with correct design patterns for following problem in MVC:

I have following classes:

```
GroupController   
GroupService 
GroupUserController  
GroupUserService   
LogService
```

(One Group may have many users)

For each controller I have `CRUD`, which is available for user's with certain role.
One of the functionality is that logged user may create group (`GroupService`). If he does that, then he must be assigned automatically to user group (`GroupUserService`). I also need to log information to `LogService` when and how (by `CRUD` or by method available only for specific role) user created group.

Currently I have something like this:

```
// GroupController.php
// Create new group
public function setAction()
{
    //code...

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->request->getPost()->toArray();
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $result = $groupService->save($data, $data['id']);

            // Add user to that group
            if ($result) {
                $groupUserData = [
                    'group' => $result->getId(),
                    'user' => $user->getId()
                ];
                $result2 = $groupUserService->save($groupUserData); // <---- service which shouldn't be here?

                if ($result2) {
                    // Some other action let's say with another service
                }

                $logData = [
                    'msg' => 'New Group created!',
                    'created_at' => new \DateTime()
                ];
                $logService->save($logData); // <---- this service shouldn't be also here?
            }

            $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->route);
        }
    }

    return $this->viewModel;
}
```

For now, this action is doing many tasks instead of just one. Isn't that breaking of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle?
I think these services shouldn't be in this controller.

**What design patterns should I use here? Chain of Responsibility? Observer? Mediator?**

Such problem I have in many controllers. I mean many actions need use of multiple services

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a facade pattern, Which aims to encapsulate/hide the complexity of certain procedures.

so you can create a class contains a method that's hold all your action logic. and simply call it from the action.

Just one point regarding to your status I think you may also need a transaction to wrap your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Layered architecture may help here, particularly hexagonal architecture:
http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture.

The best practical guide for using it which I know is provided by Vaughn Vernon in the following book:
[https://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)

The general idea: presentation logic (request/form processing) needs to be separated from application logic (use case flow logic) and from domain logic (creation and saving of group user data)